# How to Convert a String Array to a Char * Array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, c, string, exec

So I want to pass arguments to following function

```
execve(char *filename, char *argv[], char *envp[])
```

currently my `argv[]` is a string array. I want to convert it into a `char* array` so I can pass it to this function.

I have looked around and found many ways to convert a string to a `char` array but how to convert a string array to an array of char array I guess would be the right term 
Any help?

Comment: By string array, do you mean something like `string myargs[5];` and you want to pass that to `execve`?

Comment: `char *argv[]` is actually an array of `char*` elements. Each element in the array points to a `char*` string. Therefore `argv[0]` is a `char*` string that may be printed/used.

Comment: @us2012 yes by a string array i mean an array of strings
like string myargs[5]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to get the address of the data inside your `std::string`s. Note, that these are **not** required to be null-terminated, i.e., you'll need to make sure that all strings are null terminated. Also, the array passed as `argv` also needs to have the last element to be a null pointer. You could use code along the lines of this:

```
std::string array[] = { "s1", "s2" };
std::vector<char*> vec;
std::transform(std::begin(array), std::end(array),
               std::back_inserter(vec),
               [](std::string& s){ s.push_back(0); return &s[0]; });
vec.push_back(nullptr);
char** carray = vec.data();
```

When compiling with C++03, there are some changes necessary:

1. Instead of using the lambda expression, you need to create a suitable function or function object doing the same transformation.
2. Instead of using `nullptr` you need to use `0`.
3. In C++03 `std::string` is not guaranteed to be contiguous, i.e., you need an additional, auxiliary `std::vector<char>` to hold a contiguous sequence of characters.
4. There are no functions `begin()` and `end()` deducing the size of an array but they can easily be implemented in C++03:

   ```
   template <typename T, int Size> T* begin(T (&array)[Size]) { return array; }
   template <typename T, int Size> T* end(T (&array)[Size]) { return array + Size; }
   ```
5. The C++03 `std::vector<T>` doesn't have a `data()` member, i.e., you also need to take the address of the first element.

Comment: do i need to include any libraries
these are the errors i am getting
‘transform’ is not a member of ‘std’  
 ‘begin’ is not a member of ‘std’
 error: ‘end’ is not a member of ‘std’
 warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
 ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: You need to compile with the C++11 option or use a function object instead of the lambda expression and `0` instead of `nullptr`. Of course, you need to include the relevant standard headers, too (in this case `<algorithm>`, `<iterator>`, `<string>`, and `<vector>`).

Comment: i have included vector and iostream and used using namespace std

Comment: even after including <iterator> i am still getting 'begin' and 'end' is not a member of 'std' .. I am using g++ on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @user2557844: I guess, you are compiling without `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x`. In this case you might need to define a `begin()` and `end()` function.

Comment: sorry for asking more dumb questions , but exactly do i compile with std=c++11 or std=c++0x , i am new to ubuntu and compiling through terminal

Comment: @user2557844: You add `-std=c++11` to the flags passed to `g++` when compiling. If you have a `make` file, you'd add the flag to the `CPPFLAGS` or the `CXXFLAGS`. I don't know which version of `g++` you are using: depending on the version you may need to pass `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: 'In C++03 std::string is not guaranteed to be contiguous' - Can you quote the standard on this one?

Comment: @dragonroot: The standard doesn't say that it is **not** guaranteed. However, it doesn't guaranteed that it is contiguous, i.e., there is no simple quote. The requirement is in 21.4.1 [string.require] paragraph 5 in C++11: there is no equivalent in c++03.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Would it be enough to use `return s.c_str()` instead of `s.push_back(0); return &s[0];`?

Comment: @kfsone: please note that the lambda function guarantees that the string _is_ null terminated by adding a null terminator (`s.push_back(0)`). Using `c_str()` doesn't work as it returns a `char const*`, not a `char*`. You could `const_cast<char*>()` the result but I'd prefer to use `&s[0]`.

Comment: @anatoly: `c_str()` return a `char const*` not a `char*` as needed.

Comment: @kfsone: If an array of `char const*` is needed then `c_str()` can be used, of course. I didn't check the man-page but answered the question as asked.

Comment: Never mind, I'm apparently less useful than a damp towel today - it says "char *const argv", not "const char * argv". More coffee.

Comment: thanks for all the help , i just ended up using a char * array instead of a string array since conversion was to much of a fuss

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```cpp
const char *argv[]{"-l", nullptr};
execvp("ls", const_cast<char**>(argv));
```

Since they are string literals, you don't need to null-terminate them, but you still need the null string at the end of the array.